# menu item navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I use load in jquery to insert a aspx file which consists of a menu into a asp file. it gets inserted correctly with this code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"  
           src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js">  
       </script> 
       <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
       $('#menu').load('Menuin.aspx');
      });
       </script>
```

menu is just a div element.

So, what happens is the file where i refer the menu i.e. load the menu, on clicking menu item i get navigated to Menuin.aspx and not where the menu item needs to go. Do u know any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to load it like that?

Why not use `includes`?

Something like

```
<!--#include file = "Menuin.aspx"-->
```